# Is it ok to use javafx runtime of higher version than java version?

Tags: java, javafx

Everything works when i use javafx of higher version than java version.

For example javafx 16 and java 11, but might there be theoretically any problems?

Should java and javafx versions match?

Comment: And why do you want to stick to Java 11 if you could also use Java 16? For JavaFX applications there is no real argument to not always use the latest version.

Comment: @mipa It is good thing to always use the latest version in general. But java 11 has long term support - https://adoptopenjdk.net/, https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [JavaFX 16 Release Notes](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/doc-files/release-notes-16.md):

> JavaFX 16 requires JDK 11 or later.

So to answer the question, as long as your version of the JDK is at least 11, it should be compatible with JavaFX 16, but you can also use higher versions.